# making api calls conditionally using observables in angular2

Tags: angular, observable

I know this is kind of basic questions, but coming from angular1 background... its kind of troubling me and I am not able to find the best alternative for this.

So, here is my use case:

1. I want to make an api call to get the user preferences.
2. If the above api returns no preference, then call other api to get default preference.
3. Once received either of this, call a different function to arrange the widgets according to the preference.

Here is what I have tried till now:

```
getUserPreference(){
    this._myservice.getUserPrefrence(username).subscribe(response => {
      this.rawData = response;
      if(!this.rawData.length){
         this._myservice.getDefaultPreference().subscribe(response1 => {
             this.newUser = true;
             this.rawData = response1;
         })
         this.callFinalFunction(this.rawData);
      }
      this.callFinalFunction(this.rawData);
    })
}
```

But it seems above code is very novice and there must be some better way to do this.
Can any one please help me here. Please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything wrong with this code or it can be improved other than just a small mistake of calling final function inside second call. In case of first api returning no preference, final function will be called twice.

```
getUserPreference(){
    this._myservice.getUserPrefrence(username).subscribe(response => {
      this.rawData = response;
      if(!this.rawData.length){
         this._myservice.getDefaultPreference().subscribe(response1 => {
             this.newUser = true;
             this.rawData = response1;
         })
         //remove this
         this.callFinalFunction(this.rawData);
      }
      //this will be called twice if second api is already called
      this.callFinalFunction(this.rawData);
    })
}
```

Alternatively you can try using [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) or [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) operator. [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) operator is generally considered a safer default to [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) for maintaining single inner subscription.

this uses RxJS 5.5+ pipeable operators:

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

getUserPreference() {
  const userPreference$ = this._myservice.getUserPrefrence(username).pipe(
    switchMap(response => {
      if(!response.length) {
        this.newUser = true;
        return this._myservice.getDefaultPreference()
      }
      return Observable.of(response);
    })
  );
  userPreference$.subscribe(response => {
    this.rawData = response;
    this.callFinalFunction(this.rawData);
  })
}
```

RxJS < 5.5:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

getUserPreference() {
  const userPreference$ = this._myservice.getUserPrefrence(username)
  .switchMap(response => {
    if(!response.length) {
      this.newUser = true;
      return this._myservice.getDefaultPreference()
    }
    return Observable.of(response);
  });
  userPreference$.subscribe(response => {
    this.rawData = response;
    this.callFinalFunction(this.rawData);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the point of reactive programming. I have created an example in pure RxJS 6 to illustrate a better approach.

```
class UserService {
  private _user: Subject<User> = new ReplaySubject(1);
  private _preferences: Subject<UserPreferences> = new ReplaySubject(1);

  public get user$(): Observable<User> {
    return this._user.asObservable();
  }

  public get preferences$(): Observable<UserPreferences> {
    return this._preferences.asObservable();
  }

  constructor(private backendService: BackendService) {
    this.user$.subscribe(user => {
      this.backendService
        .getUserPrefrences(user.name)
        .pipe(
        switchMap(preferences =>
          preferences ? of(preferences) :
            this.backendService.getDefaultUserPreferneces())
        ).subscribe(preferences =>
          this._preferences.next(preferences)
        );
    });
  }

  public login(username: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
    let login = this.backendService.login(username, password).pipe(share());
    login.subscribe(user => this._user.next(user));
    return login;
  }

  public logout() {
    let logout = this.backendService.logout().pipe(share());
    logout.subscribe(user => this._user.next(user));
    return logout;
  }
}
```

You can subscribe to the `user$` and `preferences$` observables from any component that cares about them and listen for changes.

```
userService.preferences$.subscribe(preferences => {
  console.log('current user preferences : ', preferences);
});
```

[Full Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-51916595?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used an old version of rxjs for awhile so I hope I didn't forget the syntax.

```
getUserPreference(){
this._myservice.getUserPrefrence(username).mergeMap(response=>{
   if(!response.length){
     this.newUser = true;
     return this._myservice.getDefaultPreference();
   }
   return Observable.of(response);

}).subscribe(response=>{
  this.rawData = response;
  this.callFinalFunction(this.rawData);
})
```

Basically, you will only subscribe once. if there is no preference you will receive the defaultPreference response else you will get user preference.

Don't forget to import mergeMap and Observable.of I am sorry I don't remember the old import path's sense In angular 6 which I am currently working with there is a different rxjs version

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RxJS 6, You can handle Code like below

```
getUserPreference(){
this._myservice.getUserPrefrence(username)
   .pipe(
      switchMap(response=>{
         if(!response){
            return this._myservice.getDefaultPreference();
         }
         return of(response);
      }),
      map(response=> {
         // call the widget function
      })
   ).subscribe(output=>{
       // final output
   })
```